# Should I use std::move on functions returning std::vector?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

Consider this kind of a function:

```
std::vector<int> generateVector() {
    return std::vector<int>(10, 0);
}
```

Are there any benefits in calling generateVector() like this:

```
std::vector<int> v = std::move(generateVector());
```

..or is this kind of a move optimization now automatically done by the compiler?

Comment: Ask yourself why they are called _rvalue references_!!

Comment: Ok, now I have asked myself that. As Scott Meyers argued that you should use even int x = std::move(y) I got really confused and hence this question. I don't see the difference between these cases. And this is not a duplicate, a completely different scenario in that "possible duplicate" question.

Comment: @user2061057 `or is this kind of a move optimization now automatically done by the compiler?`. The duplicate answer states: *All return values are already moved or else optimized out, so there is no need to explicitly move with return values.* Isn't that a direct answer to your question? How isn't this a duplicate?

Comment: Are we talking about duplicate answers or duplicate questions? The question is different and std::move is used in a different way.

Comment: I can still mark this as duplicate if it makes you happy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Neither:

- There's no benefit.
- The compiler does nothing special except for compiling C++. It will probably try to do this well.

Fortunately, the expression `generateVector()` is already an rvalue, so `v` will be constructed with the move constructor, but in fact your declaration of `v` and your definition of `generateVector` are subject to copy elision, so that the construction may be treated as equivalent to:

```
std::vector<int> v(10, 0);
```

In other words, the language rules explicitly allow for copy constructors not to be called under these circumstances, even if they have side effects.

Comment: Having had that topic here before, I remember that then someone argued that using std::move would if anything make the code worse as copy elision is preferable to move construction in terms of performance.

Comment: @user2225104: I think that referred only to the return statement. I.e. `return std::move(std::vector<int>(10, 0));` would be a strict pessimisation.

Answer (score 7):

The purpose of `std::move` is to make an lvalue into an rvalue. In your case, `generateVector()` is already an rvalue, so it's redundant.

Comment: I **wont** say it is *"redundant"* (which implies it has no effect at all, which may be wrong). I'd rather say it may prevent certain optimization, such as move-elision. So it is *better* if you dont write `std::move`.

Answer (score 6):

The result of a function call that returns an object is already an *rvalue*, so applying `std::move` has no benefit.

In fact it can be a pessimisation: without `std::move`, the variable is directly initialised from a temporary, and so the temporary (and the move) can be elided.